# Cannot conform to objective-c protocol in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols

I'm trying to implement the awesome library [JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) but I  keep getting the error "'ModelMessage' does not conform to protocol 'JSQMessageData'" even though my class inherit from NSObject and I implement the required properties

Here is the protocol:

```
@protocol JSQMessageData <NSObject>

@required
 - (NSString *)senderId;
 - (NSString *)senderDisplayName;
 - (NSDate *)date;
 - (BOOL)isMediaMessage;
 - (NSUInteger)messageHash;

 @optional
 - (NSString *)text;
 - (id<JSQMessageMediaData>)media;

@end
```

and here is my class

```
import Foundation

class ModelMessage: Model, JSQMessageData {

/* Required */
var senderId: NSString
var senderDisplayName: NSString
var date: NSDate
var isMediaMessage: Bool
var messageHash: UInt
/**/

var text_: String

var id:String!
var conversationId: String!
var imageUrl: String?
var recipientId: String!
var recipientRead: Bool!

var avatar: NSData?


init(data: NSDictionary){

    super.init()

    /* Required */
    self.senderId = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"senderId")
    self.senderDisplayName = "Me"
    let dateString = getStringFromJSON(data, key: "timeStamp")
    let dateDouble = (dateString as NSString).doubleValue / 1000.0
    self.date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: dateDouble)
    self.isMediaMessage = false
    /**/

    self.text_ = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"text")

    self.id = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"id")
    self.conversationId = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"conversationId")
    self.recipientId = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"recipientId")
    self.recipientRead = data["recipientRead"] as! Bool

}

}
```

which inherit from

```
import Foundation

class Model: NSObject
{

func getStringFromJSON(data: NSDictionary, key: String) -> String {

    if let info = data[key] as? String{
        return info
    }
    return ""

}

}
```

Comment: error at which line ??

Comment: on class ModelMessage: Model, JSQMessageData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using implicitly unwrapped optionals when implementing ObjC protocols without nullability annotations. Also you can and should always use `String` instead of `NSString`.

```
var senderId: String!
var senderDisplayName: String!
var date: NSDate!
var isMediaMessage: Bool
var messageHash: UInt
```

Annotating the whole class and/or the properties with `@objc` could also help.

If that still doesn't work then check the build log as it will tell you what protocol function is missing or not implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import Foundation

class ModelMessage: NSObject , JSQMessageData {

/* Required */
var senderId: NSString
var senderDisplayName: NSString
var date: NSDate
var isMediaMessage: Bool
var messageHash: UInt
/**/

var text_: String

var id:String!
var conversationId: String!
var imageUrl: String?
var recipientId: String!
var recipientRead: Bool!

var avatar: NSData?


init(data: NSDictionary){

    super.init()

    /* Required */
    self.senderId = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"senderId")
    self.senderDisplayName = "Me"
    let dateString = getStringFromJSON(data, key: "timeStamp")
    let dateDouble = (dateString as NSString).doubleValue / 1000.0
    self.date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: dateDouble)
    self.isMediaMessage = false
    /**/

    self.text_ = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"text")

    self.id = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"id")
    self.conversationId = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"conversationId")
    self.recipientId = getStringFromJSON(data, key:"recipientId")
    self.recipientRead = data["recipientRead"] as! Bool

}

func getStringFromJSON(data: NSDictionary, key: String) -> String {

    if let info = data[key] as? String{
        return info
    }
    return ""

}


}
```

Comment: what if remove the nsobject too like `class ModelMessage:  JSQMessageData {`

Comment: No, now I have 2 errors, it's also saying that it doesn't conform to NSObjectProtocol